# how to show percent from random number generator in C

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out what to do. I'm trying to practice with rand() in C but I don't know how to do the other part.

I want the output to look like:

Coins:
  Flips: 10
    Heads: 40%
    Tails: 60%

right now I have this as my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
       int i, value;

       for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
         value = rand()%2;
         printf("Coin:\n____\n  Flips: 10\n");
         }

       return 0;

   }
```

I want it to generate heads or tails and then show a percentage of what it had. Any help?

Comment: You can edit your question

Comment: ok, I kinda understand it now but what about it I wanted to display like 10 flips, then a larger number?                                                     Coin:
    ----
      Flips: 10       Heads: 40%
                      Tails: 60%
    
    Coin:
    ----
      Flips: 100000   Heads: 49%
                      Tails: 51%

Comment: Sorry I made a duplicate because I thought the first was a bit confusing

Comment: @learningHowToCode In those cases, you're supposed to edit the first question to make it less confusing, not post the less confusing version as a completely different question.

Comment: yes, sorry I've asked a question on here before. Is there a way I can delete this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are printing during the trials when you should only be printing after they are complete. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, value;
    int heads = 0;

    srand(time(NULL)); /* seed for rand */

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
        value = rand() % 2;
        if (value == 1) {
            heads++;
        }
    }

    printf("Coin:\n____\n  Flips: 10\n");
    printf("    Heads: %d%%\n", heads * 10);
    printf("    Tails: %d%%\n\n", (10 - heads) * 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `100.0` isn't necessary in this case - `100` will do fine..

Comment: thanks, but how do you print it so like it displays how many you get from 10 flips, 100 flips, then 1000 flips?

Comment: You can make a variable for how many flips, `int numFlips = 10;`, then do `printf("Coin:\n____\n Flips: %d\n", numFlips);` Also, you will have to change the percentage calculation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit wrong with this. You're not keeping track of anything to get the percentages. Please note this is more "pseudocode". I haven't tested it so it might have a typo.

```
int main()
{
    int i, value;
    int headsCount = 0;
    int tailsCount = 0;

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
        value = rand()%2;
        if (value == 0) headsCount++;
        else tailsCount++;

        printf("Coin:\n____\n  Flips: %d\n", i+1);
        printf("    Heads: %d%%\n", (headsCount * 100) / (i+1)));
        printf("    Tails: %d%%\n\n", (tailsCount * 100) / (i+1)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only need to keep track of both `headsCount` and `tailsCount` if it's possible for a coin to land on its edge.. ;-)

Comment: True, but the readability is better and doesn't require an additional math step each time.

Answer (score 0):

`value / value` will either equal 1 or cause a division by zero.

`value / 10` will give you a result that is less than or equal to 1, but any value less than 1 will be rounded down to zero because its an integer.

`value * 100 / 10` will give you a result that is less than or equal to 100 (a percentage).

`100 - value * 100 / 10` will give you an opposite percentage.