# Using rand() when flipping a coin and rolling a die

Tags: c

I'm totally confused now. So there's this exercise in this lesson I'm reading and I'm having a hard time knowing this stuff since I'm learning C by myself. Here's the exercise:

Description:

> Write a program that will simulate the following random 
>     events using the `rand()` function in the C standard 
>     libraries. We are interested in determining if `rand()` 
>     really seems to produce a random set of values. To do this
>     we will repeat the event a certain number of times and see
>     how often we get each of the possible results. If `rand()` 
>     is truly random, and our mapping to the possible results is
>     uniform, our results should be equally likely and therefore
>     evenly distributed across all possible results.
>
> The two events will be:
>
> 1. Flipping a coin
> 2. Rolling a six-sided die
>
> Repeat each event:
>
> 1. 10
> 2. 100
> 3. 1000
> 4. 10,000
> 5. 100,000  times
>
> Within each set of repetitions, count how often each result 
>     occurs. Then compute the percentage of the total events 
>     were represented by each result.

Ex:

```
Coin:
----
  Flips: 10       Heads: 40%
                  Tails: 60%
Die:
----
  Rolls: 10       1: 10%
                  2:  0%
                  3: 20%
                  4: 30%
                  5: 30%
                  6: 10%

          ...

Coin:
----
  Flips: 100000   Heads: 49%
                  Tails: 51%

Die:
----
  Rolls: 100000   1: 17%
                  2: 18%
                  3: 17%
                  4: 17%
                  5: 17%
                  6: 16%
```

Currently I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, value, n;
    int flips[2] = {0};
    int rolls[6] = {0};

    for(n = 10; n <= 100000; n *= 10){
       for(i=0; i < n; i++){
       value = rand( )%2;
       flips[value]++;

       value = rand( )%6;
       rolls[value]++;
       }

       printf("Coin:\n____\n  Flips: %d\n",n);
       printf("    Heads: %d%%\n", ((flips[0] * 100) / n));
       printf("    Tails: %d%%\n\n", ((flips[1] * 100) / n));

       printf("Die:\n____\n  Rolls: %d\n",n);
       printf("    1: %d%%\n", rolls[0]);
       printf("    2: %d%%\n", rolls[1]);
       printf("    3: %d%%\n", rolls[2]);
       printf("    4: %d%%\n", rolls[3]);
       printf("    5: %d%%\n", rolls[4]);
       printf("    6: %d%%\n", rolls[5]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Sorry I'm not really focusing on the die outputs, just trying to get coins to work first

Comment: I answered a very similar question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21768480/1930331

Comment: They must go to the same school.

Comment: Oh got it, didn't look my bad.

Comment: yeah sorry, I thought I'd change the display name lol

Comment: You will have more success with this question if you show the code you already have (from your other question) and say more precisely what your problem is.

Comment: Results are only guaranteed to be evenly distributed if you perform them an infinite number of times.

Comment: Note that you'll get the same results every time unless you seed the random number generator with a different value each time you run it.

Comment: As of now I'm not really interested in seeding it. I actually want to have the same results just for now. I just want to make sure I understand it first

Comment: There are various steps you'll need to know how to do: (1) how to generate a choice from the return value of `rand()` when the range of values is 2 (coin flipping) and 6 (dice throwing); (2) how to accumulate the number of each type of result; (3) how to report the numbers in absolute values and as percentages; (4) how to repeat the test for different numbers of iterations.  You've not shown what you've tried in any of these areas — that's what people will be interested in helping you with. People will help you correct your code if you've made an honest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, so I do know how to make it display it being heads or tails but I'm not sure how to make it record each together. So for that I have for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
    value = rand( )%2;
    printf("Heads or tails = %s\n", value?"Tails":"Heads");
  }

Comment: Have you come across arrays yet?  If not, go find your book and read up on the basics of arrays.  If you have, using an array to store the count of the number of times you get heads and the number of times you get tails (or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 for the dice) will help.  When you've generated the counts, you can arrange to print them.  Remember that arrays are indexed from 0, so `int flips[2];` has array elements `flips[0]` and `flips[1]`.

Comment: "I'm not interested in randomly seeding the rand() function." Then you will get the same set of random numbers on each execution, and so your answer will be the same on each execution.

Comment: @Nick T For fun: I get an even distribution with 0 moves.  [Where the only winning move is NOT TO PLAY](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/WarGames#Taglines)

Comment: So is it possible to make a conditional statement in the for loop so if it is a 0 (for heads) can I place it into flips[0]? How do I place the results into the arrays?

Comment: Oh dear! You don't even need to make it a conditional statement. `value` contains a 0 or a 1. So you could use `flips[value] += 1;` or `flips[value]++;` in the loop. Afterwards, you can use another loop to print out the counts from the array, or you could use the values explicitly in one or two `printf()` statements.  With the coins, you're likely to have values 0..5 from your expression involving `rand()`, so you need to think carefully about what `throw[i]` contains (is it the count for `i` spots, or for `i-1` spots, or are you using a more exotic scheme such as `i%6`). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ However, you can probably get the basics right with an array `int throws[6];`. You will want to use a loop to print the results for this, though; writing the code out 6 times would be a programming crime. You'll need to remember to make sure that the arrays (`flips` and `throws`) are zeroed before you enter the corresponding loop with `rand()`.  You should be using functions that you write, too, but that's probably pushing things too far as yet.

Comment: Your latest update is a considerable improvement. The body of the loop is more complex than needed, but is operational.  Now you need to make sure that you zero the `flips` array before you start counting; it is not guaranteed to be zero when you start.  And then you need to wrap that code in a loop that processes 10, 100, 1000, 10,000, 100,000 flips.

Comment: ok so would int flips[2] = {0}; be ok? I'm not sure how the loop is adding to the array whenever a 0 or 1 pops up from rand()

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok so now the output is flips:10 heads:7, tails:3. Is there a way I can change the 10 to 1000? or do I have to write another for loop and just make i < 1000?

Comment: Yes, `int flips[2] = { 0 };` would be OK; so would `int flips[2] = { 0, 0 };`.  You could use another variable to drive your outer loop.  For example: `for (int n = 10; n <= 100000; n *= 10) { …current code, except 10 is replaced by n… }`.

Comment: I think I finally have it! Is the updated code correct? Well I still have to fix the percent its printing

Comment: Note that your event count is cumulative, so when you print the 100 case, you have done 10+100=110 events.  You should do the coin flips and the die rolls in the same inner loop (your die roll loop uses 10 as the bound instead of n).  Then you can initialize i once outside the outer loop and not in the inner loop, so that it picks up from where it left off in the previous iteration.

Comment: You should also use loops in the print routines, at least in the die rolls. For the coin flips, you can create an array with the "Heads" and "Tails" strings, so they can be selected by the loop variable.

Comment: @pat Ok, fixed :) Now for the percentage I want to do something like printf("    Heads: %d%%\n", ((flips[0] / n) * 100)); but I now get 0% for them.

Comment: The reason you get 0% as the output when you divide is that you're using integer division (because both `flips[0]` and `n` are integers), but you need a floating point division.  You'll need to change the `%d` to `%6.2f` or thereabouts, and use `(double)flips[0] / n` or `flips[0] / (double)n` to do the division with floating point numbers.  Or you can use `(flips[0] * 100) / n` (and `%d`), but that will only give you an integer percentage, which may well be good enough in practice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, so using (flips[0] * 100) / n  is that why I'm getting 50% and 60% because the integers in print f are rounding? Seems like 10 flips is fine but then at 100+ flips it gets over 100%

Comment: When you go to 100+ flips, you don't reset the arrays to zero, so you carry over the values from 10, and the sums add up to about 110%. The integer divisions truncate towards zero.  You can move the variable definitions inside the loop so that they are zeroed each time through the loop, or you can create a pair of loops to zero them, or you can do grotesque things like use `memset()` to set the arrays to all bytes zero.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! all of you guys are lifesavers. I learned so much just from this including little mistakes I made. I will also learn how to use stockoverflow so I don't create duplicates and ambiguous questions. You guys don't have to be bothered with my questions now I'll just finish the die part myself :)

Comment: One of my previous comments forgot to multiply by 100 to get percentages; you could multiply by 100.0 to avoid the explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and applied my suggested changes, and also show how to compute the percentages.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, value, n;
    static const char *sides[] = {"Heads", "Tails"};
    int flips[2] = {0};
    int rolls[6] = {0};

    i = 0;

    for(n = 10; n <= 100000; n *= 10){
       for(; i < n; i++){
         value = rand( )%2;
         flips[value]++;

         value = rand( )%6;
         rolls[value]++;
       }

       printf("Coin:\n____\n  Flips: %d\n",i);
       for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
           printf("    %s: %d%%\n", sides[j], 100*flips[j]/i);
       }

       printf("Die:\n____\n  Rolls: %d\n",i);
       for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
           printf("    %d: %d%%\n", j, 100*rolls[j]/i);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know an equation that will produce the percent of what was chosen? for example right now both of our codes produce heads:3% tails:7% how do we make it equal to 100%? My current one makes the Flips:10, heads:30%, tails:70% but then on 100 flips it gets messed up with Flips:10 , heads:50%, tails:60% making it equal to 110%?

Comment: Note that you've not reset the arrays each time through the loop.  The simplest fix is to define the arrays inside the outer loop, just before the inner loop.

Comment: The arrays don't need to be reset. You can do the 100 events by doing 90 more events after the first 10. Note that the i variable isn't reset, so it holds the total number of events.

Comment: Hmmm; yes, I see.  Rather subtle — not the obvious way to do it.  OK, I stand corrected.

Comment: Think of it as `i` going from 1 to 100,000, but we just take a break at 10, 100, 1000, and 10,000 to print the current state.  I figured you would want to see the same state evolving rather than resetting each time.